# Включение и отключение скрипта js или jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброе время суток. Как можно включить или отключить действие какого либо скрипта, будь то jQuery или же простой js... Пример: jQuery  скрипт придает "красивости, эффекты...", вот нужно в настройках на сайте сделать отключение эффектов, т.е. отключить или включить только определенные скрипты для отдельного пользователя

Comment: сохраняйте данные в куках или local storage и при загрузке использейте в своих скриптах

Comment: Больше вопрос стоит не как настраивать для каждого пользователя, а как включать/выключать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам и предлагают на серверной стороне написать вот это(вариант для php):

```
<? if($enableScripts) { ?>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" />
    ....
<? } ?>
```

Comment: а что вместо $enableScripts писать?

Comment: Это ваша переменная, которая отвечает за отключение эффектов на сайте.
Т.к. вам надо для каждого пользователя знать, какие скрипты подключать, то все это надо хранить в базе и доставать оттуда при авторизации пользователя. Дальше смотрите какие скрипты у данного пользователя подключены и у себя в php подгружаете соответствующие .js

Answer (score 1):

Это нужно делать на серверной стороне. Не знаю на чем у вас написана серверная часть, но на странице где подключаются скрипты нужно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
<% if(settings.enableScripts) { %>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" />
    ....
<% } %>
```

Comment: Увы, страница на php(((

Comment: Такой вариант не подойдет??

<? if($enableScripts) { ?>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" />
    ....
<? } ?>

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/), если вам нужна динамическая логика загрузки скриптов на стороне клиента.